# Assign value to 3D array, but it fills too much values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

EDIT:

This is a Vue component, with a canvas that draws a grid, the canvas has and EventListener attached, and `this.grid` stores where the user has made click (inside canvas).
init `this.grid`

```
init(){
            
            console.log("init this.grid")
            //here grid is get from data() and inicialized
            this.grid = []
            var row = [];
            var row2 = []
            for(var i=0;i<this.SIZE;i++){
                row.push(0);
            }
            for( i=0;i<this.HEIGHT;i++){
                row2.push(row);
            }
            for( i=0;i<this.SIZE;i++){
                this.grid.push(row2);
            }
            console.log("this.grid 0s")
            console.log(this.grid);
            
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasDraw");
            this.rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            this.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            this.ctx.fill();

            for (i=0; i <= this.SIZE*this.big; i += this.big) {
            this.ctx.moveTo(0,i);
            this.ctx.lineTo(this.SIZE*this.big,i);
            this.ctx.stroke();
            }
            for (i=0; i <= this.SIZE*this.big; i += this.big) {
            //ctx.lineWidth(3);
                this.ctx.moveTo(i,0);
                this.ctx.lineTo(i,this.SIZE*this.big);
                this.ctx.stroke();
            }
            canvas.addEventListener('click',this.write,false);
        },
```

This is write() function, which writes in `this.grid`

```
write(evt){
            var x = Math.floor((evt.clientX - this.rect.left)/this.big);
            var y =  Math.floor((evt.clientY- this.rect.top)/this.big);


            console.log("write(evt) call, check if");
            console.log(this.grid[x][this.h][y] == 0);
            console.log("Old value: "+this.grid[x][this.h][y]);

            if(this.grid[x][this.h][y] == 0){
                 this.grid[x][this.h][y] = 1
            }else{
                 this.grid[x][this.h][y] = 0;
            }
            console.log("New value: "+this.grid[x][this.h][y]);
            console.log(this.grid)
            
            this.posUpdated += "posicion xhy: "+x+" "+this.h+" "+y+"<br/>";
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.rect((x*this.big), (y*this.big), this.big, this.big);            
            this.ctx.fillStyle = (this.grid[x][this.h][y] == 1)? "white": "black" ;
            this.ctx.fill();
            //console.log(this.grid)
            //alert((evt.clientX%this.big) + ',' + evt.clientY%this.big);
        }
```

`this.grid` is a 3d array, initializated with zeros. Then I want to asign 1 to position(2,0,2)(x,h,y), but this code asigns 1 all over `this.grid` it looks like

but some how, now all positions where x==2 are asigned to 1.
Why? I just want (2,0,2) to be 1, not all positions(2,h,y).
It should be pretty simple but.. Thanks!.

The log
[image]

Comment: Your console output doesn't match the code you posted.  Please make sure they're consistent.

Comment: Now that you've posted initialization code, I can see you're actually assigning the same instance of the array multiple times, e.g `row2.push(row);` is pushing multiple references to the same array.  The first answer looks like it will fix the problem, but FYI that's why you saw the same value replicated.  You were seeing the **same** array multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that issue is when you were creating the 3d array. You probably used **fill** which would make references to the same array and thus result would be what you have shown.

Here is a working example:

```js
const size = 5
const fill = 0
const arr = new Array(size).fill(0).map(() => new Array(size).fill(0).map(() => new Array(size).fill(fill)))

arr[0][0][0] = 1

console.info(arr)
```